# Chrome Extension Assets - Icon Not Displaying in Search Bar

Tags: google-chrome, icons, assets

[image]Hello,

I'm currently developing a Chrome Extension. I've successfully had all my assets, including my icon, approved, and the icon is properly displayed on the listing page. However, it's not appearing in the search bar, unlike other items. How can I ensure my icon is visible in the search bar? Below is an example demonstrating that some extensions have their icons in the search bar while others don't. Does this relate to certain extensions being featured? In particular, the extension 'Testing Daily | The Tester's Home Page' does have a valid icon but it does not show on the dropdown.

Thank you.